# Questions from manuals

Tags: discussion, questions, etiquette, rules

Maybe it has been already asked. Anyway, is there any policy how to answer the question which can be precisely answered by copying and paste paragraphs from a manual. Is the link only enough or I should copy and paste corresponding text as well? Do I use comments or actual answer might be given in this case?

Comment: Links are NEVER enough. They go stale, they get deleted, they lose info.... etc etc

Comment: Always include the actual text.

Comment: Do I use comments or actual answer might be given in this case?

Comment: up to you. If it's a valid, full-fledged answer, coming from docs... you are allowed to post it, just include reference to it as well as the text ("as you can see on "insert link", the solution is "insert solution"")

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Many, many questions can, in theory, be answered by reading the manual.

I say "in theory", because if that worked in practice there'd be several thousand fewer questions asked here each day. The problem is twofold:

1. Lots of folks have trouble **understanding** the manual. Because they haven't learned enough about related topics yet, because English isn't their first language and the manual uses big words, or simply because technical writing is hard and most manuals are not well-written.
2. Lots of folks **don't even bother reading** the manual. Because they assume they won't be able to understand it, or because they don't know where to find it, or perhaps because their cousin once read a manual and died of consumption soon afterwards and hey why take chances?

Because of #1, it's usually worth taking a minute to explain *how* the manual's text answers the question being asked. Use your own words, and write to the skill level apparent in the asker's question.

**Then *quote* the manual!** Follow [these handy guidelines for quoting others' work](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing), and be *very* sure to always indicate your source. Not just because plagiarism is rude, but because if you can show even one more person where to find the answers to everything on their own, you've successfully made the world a better place.

Comment: You need to invert those two points.

Comment: 3.)  People assume the manual sucks (because most of them do) and don't want to potentially waste their time combing through the arid wasteland that is software documentation.